# composer psr-4 autoload with same key

Tags: composer-php, autoload, psr-4

i have this setup into composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/",
            "App\\": "src/App"
        }

    }
```

with this folder structure:

```
src
---App
------MyClass.php --> namespace \App;
---Somedir
------Otherdir
---------OtherClass.php --> no namespace
```

File under `src/App` folder will be loaded, file under `Somedir` not.

There is something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combinations of autoloaders, so adjust your `composer.json` to use both a PSR-4 autoloader for classes with namespace, and use classmap autoloader for those that do not have namespace:

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "src/SomeDir"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/App"
    }
  }
}
```

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload.

The disadvantage of using a classmap autoloader is that if you add or remove classes in the directories which are loaded via classmap autoloader, the classmap needs to be regenerated:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```